# Why accessing map values by using at in C++ is so slow when key values are std vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, std

I'm using `std::map` defined as `std::map<std::vector<int>, double>` and you see the key values are vector of integers. The number of members in my map is 24600. Here is the minimum working example:

`InOutLetFileVelocityWeights.h`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class InOutLetFileVelocityWeights
{
        public:
          InOutLetFileVelocityWeights();

          const std::string& GetWeightsFilePath()
          {
            return velocityWeightsFilePath;
          }
          void SetWeightsFilePath(const std::string& path)
          {
            velocityWeightsFilePath = path;
          }

          double GetValue(std::vector<int>& xyz);

          void Initialise();

        private:
          std::string velocityWeightsFilePath;

          std::map<std::vector<int>, double> weights_table;
};
```

`InOutLetFileVelocityWeights.cc`:

```cpp
#include "InOutLetFileVelocityWeights.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

InOutLetFileVelocityWeights::InOutLetFileVelocityWeights()
{
}

double InOutLetFileVelocityWeights::GetValue(std::vector<int>& xyz)
{

      double value;

      value = weights_table.at(xyz);

      return value;

}

void InOutLetFileVelocityWeights::Initialise()
{
/* Load and read file. */
const std::string in_name = velocityWeightsFilePath;

std::fstream myfile;
myfile.open(in_name.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);

std::string input_line;
/* input files are in ASCII, in format:
 *  *
 *   * coord_x coord_y coord_z weights_value
 *    *
 *     * */
while (myfile.good())
{
            double x, y, z;
            double v;
            myfile >> x >> y >> z >> v;

            std::vector<int> xyz;
            xyz.push_back(x);
            xyz.push_back(y);
            xyz.push_back(z);

            weights_table[xyz] = v;

        //std::cout << x << y << z << v << std::endl;
}
myfile.close();
}
```

`main.cc`:

```cpp
#include "InOutLetFileVelocityWeights.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

const std::string in_name = "Flow-Weights.txt";

std::vector<int> xyz;

xyz.push_back(760);
xyz.push_back(189);
xyz.push_back(368);

InOutLetFileVelocityWeights* Iolet = new InOutLetFileVelocityWeights();

Iolet->SetWeightsFilePath(in_name);

Iolet->Initialise();

double value = Iolet->GetValue(xyz);

std::cout << value << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

Any idea why it takes that long to get the value from `GetValue` function? The input file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bvv4JfdjJjCo-GKnduBdqabDJHo3UxbV/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: *but it's so slow* -- Are you running a release, optimized build, and not a debug, unoptimized build?  If you're running a debug build, please run a release build instead.  Second, you should be passing a vector by const reference, not by value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I use -O3 optimization with Intel 18.0 compiler.

Comment: If you can avoid it, I recommend not using containers as keys anywhere.

Comment: @AndyG I'm OK to change this design, but what else I can do to find `v` based on its `x, y, z` whenever I call `GetValue` function?

Comment: Moreover, in `GetValue()`, you should pass the vector parameter by const reference instead than by value. You do unnecessary copies when you cal `GetValue()`

Comment: Are all your vectors size three? I have a feeling std::array<int, 3> might yield much faster comparisons than the generic vector code. Or possibly using simd instructions on a struct containing 3 ints (you could even put 4 and leave the last one to 0 since most instructions i know of operate on 128 bits)

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, my vectors are always three for x, y, and z coordinates.

Comment: *but what else I can do to find v based on its x, y, z* -- Use a hash table.

Comment: Vectors always need to **allocate dynamic memory** once there are elements in them. If you know your vectors have exactly 3 elements, switch to arrays or tuples.

Comment: As others have said, use `std::array`, `std::tuple` or a simple `struct foo { int X; int y; int z; }` as your key for this, not a `std::vector`.

Comment: Use `std::tuple` for 3-d points. Use `std::unordered_map` as a quick container for a pointer to value map. Pass points as const references to function parameters

Comment: You are all missing the point. This is not very efficient code. *It still shouldn't take 5 hours for one lookup*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Just be aware that with a custom `struct`, you also need to provide a comparison operator to make it usable as map keys.

Comment: @DanielLangr I know.

Comment: if it takes 5 hours for that line, then maybe the problem is not really performance but a bug in your code. Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: This smells like a bug in the intel implementation of STL... Indeed provide a MWE.

Comment: It should only take 14 or 15 comparisons to find any key in your map.  This could be a library implementation bug, or an optimization bug.  What happens if you turn down the optimization level to be less aggressive?  Can you use your debugger to find out what data it is getting stuck at?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Done!

Comment: the "complete" in mcve refers to completeness in the sense that others can compile and run the code to see the same effect. We would need the input file for that, but honestly I doubt someone will put that much effort. Do you experience the same when you use random input instead of input from the file? If yes you could tell us the seed and we could run exactly the same as you do

Comment: wait a second... this single call `double value = Iolet->GetValue(xyz);` takes 5 hours? How do you measure that?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I uploaded the input file and yes that line takes 5 hours with no luck. I'm waiting to see the results but it doesn't show me anything!

Comment: Maybe a compiler or library issue.  Your example with your file on my laptop under g++ displays 0.0337005 instantly.

Comment: [Seems fast enough on quickbench](http://quick-bench.com/5PvnJKXggyljkG35PVIVEXnKWg4) (enable noop bar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some other problem, like trying to access keys that aren't there and expanding the size of the map, or it's not hung where you think it is, or there's a compiler bug or something like that.  This self-contained example reading from a file "x" containing 25000 4-tuples of ints is basically instant on my laptop with g++ and no optimization.

```c++
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::map<std::vector<int>, double> weights_table;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > allkeys;

void
loadit(char const *name)
{
  /* Load and read file. */
  std::fstream myfile;
  myfile.open(name, std::ios_base::in);

  std::string input_line;
  /* input files are in ASCII, in format:
   *
   * coord_x coord_y coord_z weights_value
   *
   * */
  while (myfile.good())
    {
      int x, y, z;
      double v;
      myfile >> x >> y >> z >> v;

      std::vector<int> xyz;
      xyz.push_back(x);
      xyz.push_back(y);
      xyz.push_back(z);
      allkeys.push_back(xyz);

      weights_table[xyz] = v;
    }
  myfile.close();
}

double GetValue(std::vector<int> xyz)
{
      double value;

      value = weights_table.at(xyz);

      return value;
}

int
main()
{
  loadit("x");
  double res=0;
  for (size_t i=0; i < allkeys.size(); ++i)
    res+=GetValue(allkeys[i]);
  std::cout << res << std::endl;
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried your code and my code in my laptop and it just gives me the result instantly, but in our cluster, it just hangs... It's gonna drive me crazy I believe to find out what's going on here...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Did you run the program on your cluster in a debugger? How do you know that the program hangs on the line you referred to? Couldn't there be some problem with a (parallel) file system, network, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You may like to use `std::tuple<int, int, int>` instead of `std::vector<int>` for your keys, as the former is much cheaper to create and copy.

And `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`. The former can give you close to `O(1)` lookup complexity (depending on your hash function) and it is more CPU cache friendly than `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::map` sorts by keys. When you insert an element, it must compare the key of the new element with many other keys (logarithmic in size). Since your keys are of type `std::vector`, imagine the work needed to insert an element, or 24600!

Also access becomes quite expensive. The complexity of `std::map::at()` is logarithmic in size, but again, you need to compare your keys which are of type `std::vector` (I'm not sure how keys of type `std::vector` are sorted, but it guess this is linear in size).

Furthermore, each time you create your `std::vector`, you are allocating dynamically, which is very expensive (you could just use a `std::array` for this job). You even create a copy when calling `GetValue(std::vector<int> xyz)` (the argument `xyz` should be passed as a `const` reference.

As an alternative, you could store your variables `x`, `y` and `z` in a `std::array<int, 3>` and use a `std::map<std::array<int,3>, double>`. This would solve your time issue.

Anyways, a `std::map` with keys of type `std::array` is as ugly as a map with keys of type `std::vector`. You should not use those kind of maps.

I don't know what the exact goal of your program is, but consider the following. When you try to get your `double` given a `triplet`, how did you decide which triplet you need? I guess you need to do this for each triplet, or for some random triplet. In both cases, you actually don't need a `std::map`. You can just store both triplets and values in `std::vector`:

```
// size
const size_t N = 24600;

// reserve space for vector of triplets (x, y, z) and vector of doubles (v)
std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> vec_triplets;
std::vector<double vec_values;
vec_triplets.reserve(N);
vec_values.reserve(N);

// for each triplet and double, store it in the vector
for ( ... )
{
    vec_triplets.emplace_back(std::array<int, 3>{x, y, z});
    vec_values.emplace_back(v);
}

// now I need to compute something using a triplet and the associated double
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx)
{
    const auto& triplet = vec_triplets[idx];
    const associated_double = vec_values[idx];
    /* do whatever you need */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why is it so slow?

Because you do much more than you need to here:

```
weights_table[xyz] = v;
```

`map::operator[]` searches the entry for the given key, inserts a key-value pair when no entry for given key exist, and then returns you a reference to the value.

If you just want to insert an element in a map you should use `map::insert`.

Then in your `GetValue` you are passing the vectors by value. This might take a while when the vectors are big.

Also make sure to enable compiler optimizations!

Comment: Initialization part is not slow, it just takes a couple of seconds. The part that is really slow is: `value = weights_table.at(xyz);`.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer depends on what you call slow, a couple of seconds can be a very long time ;)

Comment: Yes, I compare it to couple of hours that my code stuck at this line `value = weights_table.at(xyz);`.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Inserting elements as you do with keys of type std::vector and allocating the std::vector every time is extreeeemely slow!